# Getting fatal-error on Calling WCF in PHP using SoapClient over https

Tags: php, wcf, wsdl, webservice-client, soap-client

I am newbie to services, i am currently calling .net WCF service in PHP using SoapClient object. Code is as follows:

```
    $arr2=array('paymentVendorCode'=>"test1",'transactionNumber'=>123456789,'dataSource'=>'Ghana_QA','customerNumber'=>45678912,'amount'=>10,'invoicePeriod'=>1,'currency'=>'GHC','paymentDescription'=>'CashPayment','methodofPayment'=>'CASH','productCollection'=>'PRCC4');

    $certFile = "certs/Entrust.pem";
    $options = array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_1 , 'local_cert' => $certFile , 'exceptions' => true ,'trace' => true ,'wdsl_local_copy' => true ,'ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false) ,'https' => array('curl_verify_ssl_peer'  => false, 'curl_verify_ssl_host' => false)
           );

try
{
echo "SOAP Client Object Made <br />";
//To Make soap client using WSDL files offline
$client = new SoapClient("RTPP_Web_Service_WSDL_20130306/multichoice.paymentservice.wsdl",$options);    
}
catch(SoapFault $E)
{
    echo "Error:--> ".$E->faultstring;
}

print_r($client->__getFunctions());

try
{
echo $pmt_customer=$client->__call("SubmitPayment", $arr2)."<br /><br />";
}
catch(SoapFault $fault)
{
echo "came here in catch";
trigger_error("SOAP Fault:(faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}\n"."faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);  
 }
```

I have go through all WSDL files i am using and got all elements, messages, operations, parameters etc. In one of the WSDL file soap address is as follows:

```
<soap:address location="https://wispqa.multichoice.co.za/PaymentServicePerimeter/Intermediate.svc" />
```

which is actual address of service being called, normally services are called with ?WSDL at the end of url but even after adding this at the end of above url the service page appearance remains same.

One thing in service documentation is written as "The service currently does not make use of message contracts."

I am sending request to service calling one of its methods from the list that i got by calling "$client->__getFunction()". But instead of response it is giving fatal error that can be seen from the screenshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvS3d.png.

I have been working on it for a almost a week but got stuck here. Please if anybody can get me out of here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer, What i was missing is soap action for the method to be called. I have given soap action by visiting WSDL files thoroughly and found soap action for method i was calling as:

```
  $submitpayment_action   = "http://MultiChoice.PaymentService/ServiceContracts/PaymentServiceContract/SubmitPayment";
```

Also i have changed format of my request by using xml format whose excerpt is as follows(i have got this xml format by using SOAPUI tool):

```
 $submitpay = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"
xmlns:mes=\"http://MultiChoice.PaymentService/MessageContracts\" 
                                        xmlns:ser=\"http://MultiChoice.PaymentService/ServiceContracts\" 
                                        xmlns:dat=\"http://MultiChoice.PaymentService/DataContracts\" 
                                        xmlns:mcom=\"http://mcomp.scontracts\" xmlns:mcom1=\"http://mcomp.dcontracts\">
                      <soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
                        <mes:SubmitPaymentRequest>
                          <ser:PaymentRequest>
<dat:paymentVendorCode>".$vendorcode."</dat:paymentVendorCode> .......
```

and finally using this "__doRequest" SOAP method to call service method as:

```
 $response = $client->__doRequest($submitpay,$location,$submitpayment_action,SOAP_1_1,$one_way = 0);

print_r($response);
```

This show me the desired response. Now one can extract required information from the response using "simplexml_load_string($response);" , "registerXPathNamespace()" and "xpath('//string');" methods.